# How do I add serial numbers to list elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a list:

```
L = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
```

Now I want to make this into a list of tuples like so:

```
L = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5), (4, 7), (5, 11)]
```

I do not want to do this manually because in my actual code, I intend on doing this with 10,000 prime numbers. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Just add 1 to the index of each number...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `enumerate`

```
L = [2,3,5,7,11]    
L = list(enumerate(L, 1))
print(L)
>>> [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5), (4, 7), (5, 11)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!